# C#: ClassA to instantiate ClassB so that ClassB can access ClassA properties?

Tags: c#

From within instance A of ClassA, I instantiate ClassB, which starts a new thread and gets a polling loop going.  Depending on what ClassB finds, I want it to update properties in instance A of ClassA.  Is this possible?  I tried passing "this" to the ClassB constructor with no luck.  I see how I can feed ClassB any number of other class references, I just don't see how to feed it instance A of ClassA.

I will gladly use a different model if it can give me the same theoretical result.  Perhaps this can be done with events?  Many thanks in advance.

My code:

```
public class xxx
{
    yyy ggg = new yyy(this); // "this" redlined by C# Express
}
public class yyy 
{
    public yyy(xxx InstantiatedBy)
    {
        MyInstantiator = InstantiatedBy; 
    }
    xxx MyInstantiator = new xxx();
}
```

Error message is "Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context"

Comment: Of course it's possible, as long as your class/s has basic synchronization just update the class the same way as you normally would. Also add some code as it's quite difficult to visualize what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you show your _no luck_ attempt?

Comment: Just wondering, is any of the classes a Windows `Form`? Because only the UI's thread can update it, in case that's the issue you are facing.

Comment: "redlines" always come with an error message (and wont be red on everyone's system)

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in a constructor:

```
public class xxx
{
    private yyy ggg;

    public xxx()
    {
        ggg = new yyy(this); // "this" redlined by C# Express
    }
}
public class yyy
{
    public yyy(xxx InstantiatedBy)
    {
        MyInstantiator = InstantiatedBy;
    }
    xxx MyInstantiator = new xxx();
}
```